# File css/all.css not defined in asset manifest

Tags: laravel, caching, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm facing a problem others seem to have before me, but I don't find any solution to fix it. So this maybe a redundant topic but it might help me.

```
/* File: gulpfile.js */

var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        'components.css',
        'custom.css'
    ])
    .version(['css/all.css']);
});
```

The gulp command works fine :

```
[13:58:34] Using gulpfile C:\laragon\www\SmartTeam\gulpfile.js
[13:58:34] Starting 'all'...
[13:58:34] Starting 'styles'...
[13:58:35] Finished 'styles' after 314 ms
[13:58:35] Starting 'version'...
[13:58:35] Finished 'version' after 87 ms
[13:58:35] Finished 'all' after 409 ms
[13:58:35] Starting 'default'...
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Task          │ Summary                  │ Source Files                        │ Destination        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ mix.styles()  │ 1. Concatenating Files   │ resources\assets\css\components.css │ public\css\all.css │
│               │ 2. Writing Source Maps   │ resources\assets\css\custom.css     │                    │
│               │ 3. Saving to Destination │                                     │                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ mix.version() │ 1. Versioning            │ public\css\all.css                  │ public\build       │
│               │ 2. Rewriting File Paths  │                                     │                    │
│               │ 3. Saving to Destination │                                     │                    │
│               │ 4. Copying Source Maps   │                                     │                    │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
[13:58:35] Finished 'default' after 40 ms
```

After this, my public build folder contains all.css :

```
-public
--build
---css
----all-2f8e630ec5.css
----all.css.map
--rev.manifest.json
```

And in my view, I simply do :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{elixir('css/all.css')}}" />
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Where you able to fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `elixir` use `mix`:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{mix('css/all.css')}}" />
```

[Documentation on versioning](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)